# Operator <= cannot be applied to 'E' , 'E', generic class

Tags: java, merge, linked-list, generic-list

I want to merge to two linkedLists in JAVA but when i want to compare the data `h1.data <= h2.data`, I am getting that operator `<=` cannot be applied to `'E'` `'E'`.

Here is my generic class `SLLNode<E>`

```
public class SLL<E extends Comparable<E>>  {
    private SLLNode<E> first;
    public SLL(){
        this.first=null;
    }
```

Now when I want to implement the `merge` method

```
public SLLNode<E> merge (SLLNode<E> h1, SLLNode<E> h2){
    if (h1 == null)
    {
        return h2;
    }
    if (h2 == null){
        return h1;
    }

    SLLNode<E> mergedHead = null;
    if(h1.data<=h2.data)
```

I'm getting the error listed above.

Comment: Provide the code for class `E`

Comment: You probably want to use `.compareTo()`, rather than `<=`. The comparison operators only tend to work on primitives, in Java, whereas the `Comparable` interface that objects of type `E` must implement guarantees that the object will have the `compareTo()` method. e.g. `if (h1.data.compareTo(h2.data) <= 0)`

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy That worked, you can use it as an Answer.